# Puts method in ruby

Tags: ruby, parameter-passing

When I executed this,

```
puts "please enter your name" + " your name is " + gets
```

the string statements inside of the quotation marks (`""`) did not appear, but it directly showed the prompt (which is `gets`).

What happened when I executed the code? I wonder why the string statement did not show up.

Comment: It tries to concatenate everything with `+` and for that, it requires the last one (`gets`) to be evaluated.

Comment: Thanks, Aleksei. So, what you meant was that unless gets is not evaluated, the cmd 
 would show nothing because it should be a complete statement by adding all three chunks of string. Am I right? just want to re-check.

Comment: Yes, that’s correct. You might `puts "please ..."; puts "your name is " + gets;` to achieve the desired functionality.

Comment: No. Not "unless gets is not evaluated", but "unless gets is evaluated".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It becomes more obvious if you extract the parts into variables:

```
a = "please enter your name"
b = " your name is "
c = gets

puts a + b + c
```

Apparently, `gets` is called before `puts`.

To get the desired result, you could use two `puts` calls and store the input in a variable:

```
puts "please enter your name"
name = gets.chomp
puts "your name is #{name}"
```

Example session:

```
please enter your name
Caleb
your name is Caleb
```

Answer (score 1):

Before `puts` is executed, its argument is evaluated. To do that, the two `+` methods are executed. In order for the second `+` to be executed, its argument `gets` must be evaluated first.